# Replace "H" with ":" of a date and hour without changing the format of date vba

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, replace, format

I have various dates (type string) with the format dd/mm/yyyy hhHmm :
[dd/mm/yyyy hhHmm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PdMm.png)
I needed to transform them to actual type date with the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm :
[dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wolqp.png)

My problem was that when I did the replace command manually, everything worked fine, but if I implemented the replace command in a macro, it suddenly went from dd/mm/yy hhHmm to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm, which meant my data was all wrong.

I solved the problem with a *for loop* and *split function*, and am gonna put the solution here so maybe someone else with the same problem can get it as a thank you for every time I got help here:

```
lastRowRan = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
For Each cell In Range("I2:I" & lastRowRan)
        dateArray = Split(cell)
        dateArray(1) = Replace(dateArray(1), "H", ":")
        cell.Value = CDate(Format(CDate(dateArray(0) & " " & dateArray(1)), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")) 
Next
```

But obviously, as there are thousands of these dates, sometimes it can take a little while. So I've been wondering, is there a faster way?

.NumberFormat doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think i understand. When i grab the date as a string, replace "H" with ":" the format doesn't change. 
See: https://imgur.com/j3cdguK

Comment: Have a look at `DateValue`. You can than format the date as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)` and `TimeSerial(Hour, Minute, Second)` to build a real date:

```
Dim lastRowRan As Long
lastRowRan = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("I2:I" & lastRowRan)
    If Not IsDate(Cell.Value) Then
        Cell.Value = DateSerial(Mid$(Cell.Value, 7, 4), Mid$(Cell.Value, 4, 2), Left$(Cell.Value, 2)) + TimeSerial(Mid$(Cell.Value, 12, 2), Right$(Cell.Value, 2), 0)
        Cell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
    End If
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ClearDate As Date

    LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<= Change to cover your range

    For i = 1 To LastRow '<= Set the right start & end point
        With Sheet1 '<=Cahnge to fit your sheet
            ClearDate = CDate(Replace(Range("A" & i), "H", ":"))
            .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = ClearDate
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, sorry it took so long. Your code gave me an error "Incompatible Types" on this line ClearDate = CDate(Replace(Range("A" & i), "H", ":"))

Comment: Hello!Clad to hear your feedback.i run the code again and i receive no error.could you please see the image attached to my answer?it s what i get.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake I made. This works great aswell! I just needed to change the Column. My columns are I and J instead of A! Sorry about that.

Comment: @Luis Gustavo if the answer solve your problem vote it to helps others!